# What is the FAA's source for the type designators they use in IACRA?

Tags: faa

When using the FAA's [IACRA](https://iacra.faa.gov/IACRA/Default.aspx) system, an online portal used for creating applications for the issuance of a rating, you often have to choose an aircraft type to meet qualifications or to set which aircraft you'll be using during a practical test. When selecting aircraft in IACRA the type designators are different from what I'm used to. For example, a Cessna 172 K model's type designator in my experience is C172K, but in IACRA it's CE-172K. The Beechcraft Sierra would normally be B24R, but it's something like BE-23-BE24R in IACRA.

Where is the FAA coming up with these type designators they're using in IACRA?

Comment: I'm not sure if type identifier is the right word for CE-172K. Please help me improve the nomenclature if possible.

Comment: Where do you see these "official" abbreviations used?

Comment: I've seen them in IACRA. On type ratings. In other pilot's Airline Apps. Occasionally on flight plans. For example the Piper Cheyenne I is a PA-31-500T in one place then PAY1 in another. Just trying to find definitions for the identifiers and associated nomenclature.

Comment: Did you use the word "official"? I looked at IACRA and I saw it there, not sure where it came from though. I'll do a little research and see if I can figure it out though.

Comment: It looks like the FAA calls it "model designation". It can be found in the [type certificate data sheet](http://www.aerofiles.com/tc2.html) (TCDS). There is a relationship between "type rating designation" and "model designation". Some designations can be found in this [Excel file](http://registry.faa.gov/TypeRatings/).

Comment: I found this ICAO list of "type designations". http://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: @mins based on that **"172, A, B, C, D, E, F (T-41A), G, H (T-41A), I, K, L, M, N, P, Q, R, S = 3A12"**  shouldn't it then be 3A12 and not CE-172?

Comment: So far, I have checked the [ICAO type designators](http://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/Search.aspx), the [FAA type designators](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/Order_7360.1_.pdf) and the other resources seen here and I have yet to find this **CE**-172 anywhere.  Good question.

Comment: @RyanMortensen: That's not clear to me. I understand [3A12 is the TC number](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/A444ABC8F3357F6C86257EA4004E8AE6?OpenDocument), which encompasses different models.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

This is the FAA's Type Certification Data Base, which lists all type certificates issued by the FAA.

Note:  this only covers certified aircraft and not experimental or homebuilts.

http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/Frameset?OpenPage

Comment: You answered before I rewrote the question, but this is a good resource. Thank you.